# Send Daily Emails via single nested loops function

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, datatable

I am creating a web page that will be run once a day to send email notices to supervisors.  I want each supervisor to get a single email that contains data about all of their employees, of which might have multiple events.

I have some data like this:

```
supervisorEmail |   employeeID  |   eventDate   |   eventDetails
===================================================================================================
george@blah.org |   jones       |   2014-03-18  |   Watch a movie
george@blah.org |   jones       |   2014-03-20  |   Convention registration
george@blah.org |   smith       |   2014-03-20  |   Convention registration
george@blah.org |   smith       |   2014-03-20  |   Convention registration
gayle@blah.org  |   nloya       |   2014-03-13  |   some other stuff
gayle@blah.org  |   nloya       |   2014-03-25  |   this and that
```

I start by retrieving all the above data and put into a DataTable.
Next I need to group by supervisor so each gets an email.
Within each email I need the rows filtered for that supervisor.  I see how LINQ can be used for some of this.  I'm lost at the moment for all of it.  Could I get a shove in the right direction at least?

Comment: "a web page that will be run once a day" why not do it as a console app that is scheduled?

Comment: So take a look at the list of all of the LINQ methods.  (There really aren't *that* many.)  One of them should stand out as a possibly useful tool for grouping items by some property.

Comment: Web page vs console app is not the issue here!  I'm not that far so how about sticking to the topic of the question?  Is this not a good place for asking a question unless I'm a super level expert?

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data by `supervisorEmail`:

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(d => d.supervisorEmail);
foreach(var g in groups)
{
    SendEmail(g.Key, g);   // g is an IEnumerable<some type> with the data for that supervisor
}

public void SendEmail(string supervisorEmail, IEnumerable<some type> data)
{
    // send data to supervisor
}
```